# Ionic: Why isn't my HTTP.GET not loading my image?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load images from a json file into my ionic application to create a gallery but it isn't working. I'm trying to follow this guide https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/ but use a HTTP.GET request instead.

HTML:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 3].src}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('http://myjson.com/3lkge')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.images = data.images;
            })
    }

});
```

Comment: Did you see any error messages in the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah,

It's because of the link you was passing into to the get request.

The link: 'http://myjson.com/3lkge' - was for the website, not for the direct json data.

Correct json url for get request: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/3lkge'

Code should look like this:

```
$scope.getImages = function() {
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/3lkge')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.images = data.images;
        })
}
```

Tested in your codepen and it works.

Comment: Ah thank you. Any idea it isn't loading the fourth image corrently? http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Comment: Yes, because you have no fourth image in your json ;).

Comment: Fixed it now. Missing a }

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not putting images onto the object $scope.data.images. You're putting them onto $scope.images. In your html remove data.images, and use images instead. Also you need to remove your index stuff.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div class="col col-25">
        <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work :/. Here's a codepen which i've set up: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Comment: If you're trying to limit your filter to only display 4 elements, use the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo.  Also use filters in general to choose which image to display in an ng-repeat. I hope this helps.

Comment: In all honesty, I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your html your binding is wrong.

This:

```
 <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
```

Should be this:

```
<img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
```

data.images is not on scope, its local to your `.success` method.

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work :/. Here's a codepen which i've set up: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Comment: Its not going to work in codepen - getting this console message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myjson.com/3lkge. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Your Scope variable is incorrect.

The "ng-src" attribute should be binding to the following:

{{images[$index].src}}

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work :/. Here's a codepen which i've set up: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG